# How to populate dropdown menu from my local hosted database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm really stumped right now. I've been stuck with this problem for a number of days now and frankly, I'm getting sick and tired of it.

I have this database table: https://gyazo.com/9d1b014ecdba1e244c2f6957b6d9397c

(notice `FlightsTable`)

My goal is to populate a dropdown menu based on the values from the "**Departure**" section.

I've tried lots of things and yet I still cannot get to grips with it.

Here's my model:

```
public class FlightModel
{
    public int FlightID { set; get; }
    public string Departure { set; get; }
    public string Arrival { set; get; }
    public int NumberOfSeats { set; get; }
    public int NumberOfFlights { set; get; }

}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult BookFlight()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

FlightDBEntities (from the FlightsDBModel)

```
namespace Project_v3.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class FlightsDBEntities : DbContext
    {
        public FlightsDBEntities()
            : base("name=FlightsDBEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<FlightsTable> FlightsTables { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the files: http://gyazo.com/31b447387f349fbbe541f44a358c3096

How do I make the dropdown work in my view for BookFlight? I'm really struggling with this so step-by-step solutions so I can understand every step would be greatly appreciated. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, this is an example:

You'll need something that actually creates your selectlist:

```
public SelectList GetAsSelectList()
{
    var depts = from f in db.FlightsTables 
                        select new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = f.Departure,
                            Text = f.Departure
                        };
     return new SelectList(depts, "Value", "Text");
}
```

If departures are held in their own table, then it would be better to select them from there, using the `Id` primary key field as the selectlist's `value` field

I've assumed that the selectlist will be shown on the same page as `FlightModel`. If this is the case, then your model needs a property for the selectlist:

```
public SelectList DepartureList { get; set; }
```

Your controller method needs to create a FlightModel instance, populate it with whatever you want to show (including the selectlist) and pass it to the View:

```
public ActionResult BookFlight()
{
   var model = new FlightModel
   {
       DepartureList = GetAsSelectList()
   };
   return View(model);
}
```

Depending on what you want the user to do with the selectlist, you display it in the view like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Departure", Model.DepartureList)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply! I really do appreciate it. So, I should place the `SelectList GetAsSelectList()` into the `FlightModel.cs`? Or am I looking at something else here?

Comment: `GetAsSelectList()` can be in model class, but probably better to have it in your controller.

Comment: Another question in regards to `var depts = from f in db.FlightsTables`. I get an error saying that db does not exist in the current context? Is there a missing line here? (I've placed `GetAsSelectList()` in my controller)

Comment: It's because it doesn't have a reference to your data classes.  How are you accessing the database elsewhere in the project?  Just use the same approach for this.

Comment: Thank the gods of programming! I have it working now. You are an absolute star! Is there a way for me to refine the dropdown so that it only shows `London` for example once? And then create a different dropbox which contains the `Arrival` destinations?

Comment: Yes, use `.Distinct()` on the end of the query: `var depts = (from f in db.FlightsTables..... }).Distinct();`  Note that the whole query is now wrapped in brackets `()`

Comment: For the arrivals, you just need to basically duplicate the code, but you'll use `Value = f.Arrival` instead of `Value = f.Departure`

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, select the distinct departures

```
IEnumerable<string> departures = db.FlightsTables.Select(f => f.Departure).Distinct();
```

and assign to to a `ViewBag` property (or better, use a view model with a property for the `SelectList`)

```
ViewBag.DepartureList = new SelectList(departures);
```

and in the view (unsure what the property you want to bind to - you have not shown your model for the `Booking`)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YourProperty, (SelectList)ViewBag.DepartureList, "-Please select-")
```

I suspect you may need to modify your flight table. You have a ID column but the have a column for number of flights. Surely you would need information about departure and arrival times for each flight?

Edit

Further to comments, your booking model may look something like.

```
public class BookingVM
{
  public List<FlightModel> FlightList { get; set; } // to display available flights
  public string Departure { get; set; } // bind to DepartureList
  public int FlightID { get; set; } // bind to FlightID in a dropdown that displays the arrival locations
  public int Seats { get; set; } // number of seats booked
  public SelectList DepartureList { get; set; } // unique departures
}
```

You would need to handle the `.change()` event of the Departure dropdownlist, use ajax to pass the selected departure to a controller method that returns the flightID and arrival locations (and probably the number of available seats for each flight) and use that to populate the second dropdownlist (bound to `FlightID` and displaying the arrival locations).

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for the reply! I have not yet made the booking however the idea was to assign a flight ID or both the Departure + Arrival to a user. At the moment, I was going to do it step by step (ie. create a dropdown for the departures, dropdown for the arrivals, and make sure they both come from the database. After that I can assign the values from these dropdowns to the user etc

Comment: See edit - I have a few doubts about your flight table. I'll update again with a sugestion about the booking model.

Comment: Quick question. Where's the `db` coming from? in the first line of code that you posted?

Comment: Updated again with suggested booking model. `db` is your database context - looking at your question I assume its `FlightsDBEntities`

Comment: I got it now thanks! Also, thank you very much for the edit on how to set up my booking model.

Comment: Note the first line or code in my answer (it displays the unique departure locations in one line of code - in reference to your last comment in markpsmith's answer (and you don't need to do unnecessary things like create `IEnumerable<SelectList>` and then create a  `SelectList` (which is  `IEnumerable<SelectList>`) from it)

Comment: That makes good sense. I'll experiment with both of these methods to make sure I understand both and of course make sure I know how to use them efficiently.